# android developpement, making markers visible on google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I want to know if the markers that a user adds in an android application using google maps are vesible by other users of the same application.

Comment: If you sync them over the internet, that would be a possibility. Whats is the question, do you want to sync markers online?

Comment: yes, is it possible to do that using google servers only

Comment: Unfortunately sharing the markers in an android application across users is not possible with the standard Google API's available as far as I know.